# get value of function during debug xcode

Tags: xcode, function, debugging, methods

I am new to xcode/ios development. I need to know can we get the value of a function during debug process? Like

```
[super getUserName];
```

In eclipse we can get the return value by selecting the text and then by selecting disply option from the menu.

How to deal with in xCode?

PS: I am using xcode 4.6.2

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean methods. Use any of these

```
po [x method]
po x.variable
```

where x is a class or instance, eg:

```
[NSThread callStackSymbols]
```

If the value returned is a primitive type use `p` instead `po`.

To print a function use

```
expr (void)printf("hi");
```

To change a variable:

```
expr (void) [gift setName:@"PS3"];
```

If you pause execution and call `super`, eg:

```
po [super description]
```

Xcode may crash because it's not the most stable IDE in the world.